# How to get disable products in product collection in magento2.2

Tags: magento2, stock-status

I am trying to get product collection with all enabled/disabled products. It works fine until I upgrade Magento to 2.2. Now It's not fetching disabled products in collection. Here is my code -

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,

    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('diamond_vendor', array('in'=>$vendor))
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in'=>array(1,2)))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$notin_ids))
                    ->setPageSize($noOfProducts)
                    ->load();
    }
}
```

In this I also tried with  -

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('stock_status_index.stock_status IN(1,0)');
```

But its not making any effect.

Plz help me in this.

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In magento 2.2, I have also faced this problem and it looks like bug to me but still we can use a workaround of using 'getPart' & 'setPart' functions to alter the load query of collection.

Note: Make sure you are using it in your custom module and not changing any magento core functionality or code.
Please try to use it as:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('diamond_vendor', array('in'=>$vendor))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$notin_ids))
                            ->setPageSize($noOfProducts)
                            ->load();
            // Patch to alter load and get disabled products too
       $collection->clear();
            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('where');
            foreach ($where as $key => $condition)
            {
                if(strpos($condition, 'stock_status_index.stock_status = 1') !== false){
                    $updatedWhere[] = 'AND (stock_status_index.stock_status IN (1,0))';
                } else {
                    $updatedWhere[] = $condition;
                }   
            }
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart('where', $updatedWhere);
            $collection->load();
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to set flag after collection to get disable products from collection object like below

```
// Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory

$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
return $productCollection;
```