# Magento 2: Show disabled/out-of-stock products in foreach loop

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, product-collection

I am using `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` class to fetch the product collection.

> Magento version: **2.2.6**

I am trying to fetch both **enabled** & **disabled** products with the following code

> status > 0, as in Magento, Enabled = 1 and Disabled = 2

```
$collection = $this->productCollection
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0));
```

When I print the product collection data:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($collection->getData());
echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 27
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => virtual
            [sku] => my-product-905546
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-12-04 10:18:06
            [updated_at] => 2018-12-04 10:20:31        
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 26
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => virtual
            [sku] => test-123-897069
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-12-03 06:38:39
            [updated_at] => 2018-12-04 09:57:10
        )
)
```

In the above product result:

- one of the product is **disabled** and out-of-stock (**sku:** `my-product-905546`)
- the other product is **enabled** and in-stock (**sku:** `test-123-897069`)

When I loop through the product collection, it only prints the enabled product name.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku();
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Result:

```
test-123-897069
```

Expected Result:

```
my-product-905546
test-123-897069
```

Why is this so?

Any solution to print the disabled/out-of-stock product inside the foreach loop (**load both enabled and disabled products into the collection**) please?

Comment: By default disbled products are not loaded into collection

Comment: @MilindSingh How to load disabled products into the collection?

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211354/59216

Comment: @MilindSingh Thanks for the link. It solved the issue of displaying out-of-stock products. However, I am still not able to display disabled products.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
$collection->joinTable( 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array("stock_status" => "is_in_stock") )
           ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 2 ) );
```

Comment: No,  it's not working.